# Data visualisation on pyspark (Type Error)

Tags: python, pyspark, data-visualization, bar-chart

I'm working with a large dataset that I have uploaded to pyspark and so far i've been able to do basic statistics but I am having trouble trying to draw the bar chart and histogram for a specific attribute.

So far the code I have is:

```py
#barchart for TotalCharges

data = churn_data.groupBy(churn_data.TotalCharges.cast(IntegerType())) \
  .count().orderBy("count", ascending=False).collect()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,3,2])
for _ in data:
  ax.bar(_[0], _[1])
  print(_)

print(data)  
plt.show()
```

The error I am getting is:

```
TypeError: the dtypes of parameters x (object) and width (float64) are incompatible
```

Can someone advise on how to fix this? (Please note I have been able to plot the bar charts for other attributes in my dataset other than the attribute "Total Charges", which is the only attribute that is not an Integer, all the observations for this attribute are two decimal places.

Comment: Maybe try `toPandas()` instead of `collect()`?

Comment: got it working, thanks!